# JS/PHP, time of date

Tags: javascript, php, html

i would like to ask, if someone know to to make in JS or PHP time of date.

Or how long we're together, like 70 days or 2 month and some days, and all day add 1 more day. I have something whats work, but on begging of that time is - .
I spent a lot time with making something what should work. But nothing.

There is that code with that -

```
<script charset="UTF-8">


function daysTill() {

  var day=      8 
  var month=    12 
  var year=    2016 
  var event=    "relationship with my ♥"
  var end =     "days of"


  var daystocount=new Date(year, month -1, day)
  today=new Date()
  if (today.getMonth()==month && today.getDate()>day)
  daystocount.setFullYear(daystocount.getFullYear())
  var oneday=1000*60*60*24
  var write = (Math.ceil((daystocount.getTime()-today.getTime())/(oneday)))
  document.write('<strong>'+write +'</strong> '+end+' '+event)
}

  daysTill();

</script>
```

if someone know, please help me. Thanks ♥

Comment: Why don't you just use a simple website included with a calculator? http://www.countcalculate.com/love/ultimate-relationship-calculator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [getTime() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) returns the time in milliseconds so to convert it to days you divide that by 86400000 (1000 for seconds * 60 for minutes * 60 for hours * 24 for days):

```js
var relationship = new Date("2016/12/08");
var today = new Date();
var days = Math.ceil((today.getTime() - relationship.getTime()) / 86400000);

document.write(days + " days have pass since the start of the relationship.");
```

Comment: @Memousek, glad to help you out. Hope you the best of luck! ♥

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "JavaScript date maths"

```
// new Date(year, month (0-11!), day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds); 
var dateFuture = new Date(2017, 3, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0);
var dateLongAgo = new Date(2001, 8, 11, 8, 46, 0, 0);
var dateNow = new Date();

//86400000 millis per day
//floor --> all unter a full day shall be 'no day'
var daysSince = Math.floor((dateNow-dateLongAgo)/86400000); 
var daysUntil = Math.floor((dateFuture-dateNow)/86400000); 

console.log("long ago\t", dateLongAgo);
console.log("now is\t\t",dateNow);
console.log("then\t\t",dateFuture);
console.log("days since\t",daysSince);
console.log("days until\t", daysUntil);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using external libraries, Carbon is a nice tool extending DateTime

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

It returns many kinds very nicely formatted dates -- months, days, hours etc included.

Comment: Oh common dont upvote this kind of answer , is it answer or comment.

Comment: Maybe a comment indeed, but I don't mind being downvoted if it helps people.